# What are the reasons to use Angular Flex-Layout?

Tags: html, css, angular, flex3, angular-flex-layout

In one of the projects i'm working on, the team decided to use angular/flex-layout.
I was wondering, what are the reasons to use it at all ?
I could only find reasons against.

For example this code:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
</div>
```

The first "best practice"/"separation of concerns" regarding html & CSS we are all familiar with, is the separation of content and style; with flex-layout we totally lose it.
it looks like an inline style, which is a really bad practice.

the only good thing I can think about is using variables directly to flex-layout directives, but we can achieve that using ngStyle directive as well.

I'm really interested in your opinions, What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests [Angular Flex-Layout] is a library for laying out your components on your web page. The library does not provide a means for styling, fonts, or colours, as those tasks are delegated to traditional styling in your application. Angular Flex-Layout deals with component positioning and works well with or without Angular Material. It is also built by the Angular team and supported by the community.

Some of the main advantages for using Angular Flex-Layout are:

- The library is a pure Typescript Layout engine.
- Uses HTML markup to specify layout configurations.
- Independent of Angular Material.
- A responsive API can specify different layouts, sizing, visibilities, viewport sizes, and display devices.
- Includes CSS Grid.
- Requires no external stylesheets.

Comment: Imo, I can't find those as advantages, only the responsive API you mention can help managing media queries etc.
Also using inline style does not require an external stylesheets, but that's a really bad practice.

Comment: Biggest disadvantage is that this library is now [deprecated and no longer supported by Angular](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127)